# Authenticate http call to GitHub APIs in java

Tags: java, httprequest, github-api

I'm working on a project which requires to call GitHub APIs several times and I reached the limit of 60.
I read that with authentication you get 5000 as limit but I can't understand how I can authenticate my requests in my java program. I got my authentication token on Github and this is the way I'm building the request in java:

```
// create client
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

// create request
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits"))
                .build();
```

what should I add to the request to authenticate it?
I tried adding the header `authToken:myToken` but it didn't work.

Comment: How did you get the token ? using an API call ? If that is an access token use the header as this : `Authorization: token<the token>`

Comment: I managed to solve my problem and posted the solution. Thanks for the reply anyway !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**:

Once I got the token on my GitHub profile > Settings > Developer Settings > Personal Access Tokens, I added the header `"Authorization: Bearer "myToken" " to the http request so the request becomes:

```
// create client
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

// create request
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization","Bearer <myToken>")
                .uri(URI.create("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits"))
                .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Http request header `Authorization` to your request and the header should contain your token. So if your code is written on Java 11 or higher as it appears to be than you need to change your code to:

```
// create client
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

// create request
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/commits"))
                .header("Authorization", "your-tocken")
                .build();
```

Comment: I just lost 1 hour thanks to this answer.
You need to write .header("Authorization", "token ghp_....")
that is, in front of your token you need "tokenSPACE"